# AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'description'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I've been banging my head for a week with this error and I cannot find the solution. I inherited a legacy app written in Django. I am familiar with Django but not an expert. This application  works well in many different environments, Heroku and some other Linux distributions. We required to install a couple of new instances in Debian GNU/Linux 10. Most of the application works well but we started getting exceptions on some commands.
The exception is clear, I get the aforementioned error in the title. One of the classes fails to bind a property that works nearly anywhere. In fact, I wrote a test command that mimics loading most of the objects that fail in the process and I don't see any error.

After adding a lot of debug information I could nail it down to a couple of **unicode** methods:

```
class PrinterAutomaticRule(models.Model):
    printer = models.ForeignKey(Printer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='automatic_rules')
    description = models.TextField(u'DescripciÃ³n', null=True, blank=True)
    # ... (mode irrelevant code)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return u'some text with weird chars Ã³ {0}: {1}'.format(self.printer, self.description
            if self.description else u'another text with weird chars Ã³')

class Printer(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='printers')
    name = models.CharField(u'Nombre', max_length=200)
    # ... (mode irrelevant code)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0} ({1})'.format(self.name, self.restaurant.name)


class Restaurant(models.Model)
    # you  can imagine the rest
```

Because this is not English there are some weird chars and it's required in the way it was created to display on the website. The application immediately works if we replace half of those unicode methods with whatever we want. You can see there there is also another object (self.printer) which yields another unicode method within.

This application works in Heroku and it works in other environments including Windows. I guess I have an environment issue that is hidden somewhere. Unfortunately, we cannot change the logic due to the fact this app has a terrible way of dealing with tons of data and it filters out information sometimes using the object representation. It is a huge app that has dozen of thousands lines in the model.

I also failed to produce more debug output with Django, there are a lot of try/catch that produce logging information in the database and it's not that easy to go and replace all of them. I ended up rewriting tons of code but this is a working application in other environments so I am sure I am missing something.

If I replace that particular code, there is another unicode that fails, and I replace the next one  there is one more failing and so forth. Again, this works well in many other places.

One more detail, this application uses Postgres SQL. I know Postgress deals very well with unicode and even converts in case there are mismatches, not failing.

EDIT

Adding more information. There is one particular line that always fails, no matter what.

```
    for printer in order.restaurant.active_printers.filter(type__description=PrinterType.fiscal_description):
        jobs = [print_job for print_job in [rule.get_print_job(order, now=now) for rule in printer.active_rules()]
                if print_job]
        if jobs:
            fiscal_print_job = jobs[0]
```

it is a bit convoluted but it always fails. The reason is at some point Django calls unicode in rule or active_rules (which ends up in the code I mention above for PrinterAutomaticRules) or printer.

Comment: self doesn't seem to be applied in the code snippet, so self.printer and self.descripion wouldn't exist. If that code is in a class then consider passing in (self) like "def __unicode__(self):

Comment: I apologize if this doesn't look clear, I will edit it to indicate the rest of the code

Comment: So just to get updated here a bit, are you still getting an error and if so what would that error be?

Comment: Sharing the error logs/traceback might help as well. I know you said you pinpointed it to those lines, but a fresh set of eyes might help find something you missed (happens to everyone)

Comment: The title.. AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'description'. It seems it cannot bind the description. This code runs without issues in other Linux environments, Heroku and also Windows. But it fails in this particular Debian distribution

Comment: There is a particular line what it makes it fail always. I don't know how Django manages the objects but when it executes that line it seems to render the object and execute the __unicode__ method which makes it fail

Answer (score 0):

Even when I am still doing some research, this is what I found.
I use PyCharm to code, so the encoding is fine. As everyone probably knows, GIT stores everything as a binary blob so there are not conversions in the blob itself.
When I **clone** a specific branch without going back and forth using checkout it works perfectly. The problem occurs always when I clone the entire repository and I switch back and forth to different branches. In this case the entire encoding get messed up, the reason Django fails is different, it cannot deal with the encoding and it fails to bind my properties.
Everything works well in two cases:

- Clone the branch using git clone --branch
- Using Windows

I tried Ubuntu, Debian, and some combination of versions, all of them fail. I couldn't find the root cause yet.